# Cluster Analysis for data with preexisting cluster membership restrictions

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, constraint

I am trying to see if a particular set of plant morphological data (sepal dimensions, corolla dimensions, etc.) can, through cluster analysis, suggest a number of distinct species in the data set.  Since each plant can (and generally does) have multiple flowers, each plant has multiple data tuples in the data set.  Clearly, a given plant can only be one species, but without restrictions different data tuples from the same plant may be classified as different species.  How can I ensure that all data from a given plant is assigned to the same cluster?

Comment: It looks like you want constrained clustering with "must link" constraints. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_clustering

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.  That does seem to be what I am looking for; now I just have to find or code an implementation!

Comment: My spss macro of hierarchical cluster analysis !hieclu contains a feature of such form of constraint (visit my web-site, collection "Clustering"). This constraint amounts to first do clustering inside the preexistent clusters, then turn further to cluster among those.